# How to solve seg fault?

Tags: c

This code has seg fault on my Mac when main function is in other .c file. When main function and this function in the same file, it works good.

```
List *search( int k )   
{       
List *current = head->next;

   while (current != NULL && current->data != k)
      current = current->next;

   if (current != NULL && current->data == k)
   {
      printf("data is found!%d\n", current->data);
      return current;
   } 

   return NULL;  
}
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You need to provide a `main` function where you show how you use (aka call) the functions.

Comment: Your use of head seems strange but it is not necessarily a bug. Normally you would have code like `if (head == NULL)` instead of `if (head->next == NULL)`.

Comment: I post the main function.

Comment: `head` is uninitialized... or maybe it happens in `init` ?

Comment: Yes, but the requirement of it is the head point to dummy node with data -1. head->next is the first node. BTW, the data of node should be positive.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post     init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the remove function, you must update `tail`if the list becomes empty.

```
int removeFirst()
{
   List *nodeToRemove;
   int dataToRemove;

   if (head->next == NULL)
   {
      prtError("Empty list!");
      return -1;
   }
   else
   {
      nodeToRemove = head->next;
      dataToRemove = nodeToRemove->data;
      head->next = nodeToRemove->next;
      free(nodeToRemove);

      // Update tail if list is empty
      if (head->next == NULL)
      {
          tail = head;
      }

      return dataToRemove;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the searching part still cause segmentation fault.

Comment: @Pan.J I can't reproduce the seg fault - see here: http://ideone.com/JKj3AO

Comment: I see. The main() is a separate file. I use command cc list.c listMain.c to compile it, and 11 warnings are showed. Then a.out and seg fault. I merge two files, and the result is prefect. I just so wonder it.

Comment: Maybe it's the problem of my Mac. I tried to connect Linux machine. It works. Thanks so much.